# Are there benefits of creating tables using "display: table;" style rather than using old school "table" tag?

Tags: html, css

Are there benefits of creating tables using "display: table;" style rather than using old school "table" tag ?

And I know that IE7/8 don't support "display: table;".

Thanks!

Comment: it often depends on what is more semantic. If you have a list of links, it may be more appropriate to tell Google or Bing that they are part of an unordered list, rather than a table and so, display: table would be more appropriate. Tables have their place, don't be scared to use them now.

Comment: It also is more semantic to a screenreader user. Design for humans first, search engines second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. There are enough hierarchical requirements on `display: table` and its relatives (particularly `display: table-row` and `display: table-cell`) that it's generally infeasible to use those properties to style arbitrary elements as a table. The main purpose I've heard for these properties is to make it possible to define the behavior of a `<table>` purely in terms of user agent CSS, rather than making it a special case.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `display:table` & old school `table` are different because if we want to show `data representation` for example **"salary of the employee & name, age etc"** then using old school `table` better than `display:table` but on the other hand if we want some functionality of `table` according to need of the design For example **"flexible divs"** etc then `display:table` is best.

*NOTE:* `display:table` work till `IE8`

Comment: As sandeep says, the benefits are that you can get properly chosen HTML elements, marking up their data with the appropriate meaning, to *render* like tables.  HTML is for conveying meaning, CSS is for configuring appearance.

Answer (score 0):

tables by default are set to display:table; the benefits of display:table can be extended when you apply them to nontabular data.